# div scrolling using setTimeout()

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
setTimeout(function(){ 
       $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: $('#section2').offset().top }, 1000);
 }, 4000);
```

why the above code not working chrome browser ?

The above code is working in Mozilla firefox browser and not working in google chrome browser.

I have a 6 full screen div there id's like section1, section2,...section6.

I want to scroll down div automatically section1 div into section2 div.

please suggest me for above code.

Comment: for me It works on chrome, can you open up your console and tell me if you see any errors?
also what will you see when you paste $('#section2').offset().top and $('body').height() in your console.

Comment: hi Mohammadi no error there but i am not getting any out put

Comment: would you please make fiddle on http://jsfiddle.net/ so I can exactly see what you are doing?